# Problems detecting whether div is hidden or visible

Tags: jquery

I wrote a small list menu that is shown when the user clicks on a button and it will hide if he clicks anywhere outside of the menu. However if he clicks on the button again nothing happens because jQuery doesn't seem to notice the changed visibility.

JS Code:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    var container = $('#inbox_menu');
    if (!container.is(e.target)) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
$('#inbox_menu_btn').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#inbox_menu').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#inbox_menu').show();
    } else {
        $('#inbox_menu').hide();
    }
});
$('#inbox_menu li').on('click', function () {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#inbox_menu').hide();

    // other stuff
});
```

It appears that `if($('#inbox_menu').is(':hidden'))` always returns true even if the menu is visible. The same thing happens if I change this line to `if($('#inbox_menu').css('display') == 'none')`

Did I miss something here?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/om8r2044/) for demonstration.

Comment: [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) `How :hidden is determined was changed in jQuery 1.3.2. An element is assumed to be hidden if it or any of its parents consumes no space in the document. CSS visibility isn't taken into account (therefore $( elem ).css( "visibility", "hidden" ).is( ":hidden" ) == false)`

Comment: Instead of testing visibility, why not use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Comment: @JNF I dont set the visibility attribute but the display attribute. If the element has `display:none` it consumes no space in the document and therefore `if ($('#inbox_menu').is(':hidden'))` should return false if the element is visible and hide the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you need.  The document mouse up was causing issues with the other function.
I've also changed show/hide to toggle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/om8r2044/5/)

```
$(document).click(function () {
   $('#inbox_menu').hide();
});

$('#inbox_menu_btn').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#inbox_menu').toggle();
});

$('#inbox_menu li').on('click', function () {

    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#inbox_menu').hide();

    // other stuff
});
```

Comment: Yeah this works and the problem is very obvious to me now ;D. Thank you.